# Не работает программа с нейронной сетью

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Сам код.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root    

def your_funcs(X):

    x, y = X
    # all RHS have to be 0
    f = [x + y**2 - 4,
         np.exp(x) + x * y - 3]

    return f

sol = root(your_funcs, [1.0, 1.0])
print(sol.x)
```

Проблема в том, что у меня не работает код, выдает куча ошибок.
Устанавливал numpy и scipy через cmd. Но все равно не работает.
[image: Скриншот из PyCharm с ошибками]

Answer (score 1):

1. Зачем вы свой модуль назвали numpy, а в нем задаете импорт модуля numpy. Для начала измените, а потом будем думать дальше.
2. Что значит "Устанавливал numpy и scipy через cmd." И главное - зачем? Вы думаете, ваших знаний хватит, что бы сделать это лучше, чем conda или pip?
3. Причем тут "нейронная сеть", да и вообще -  неработающая программа, если вы просто модуль нормально не подключили?
4. Ну и вам, как новичку. Возможно этот первый вопрос вам простят, но за пример кода, представленный в виде скрина, а не в виде воспроизводимого скрипта обернутого в соответствующий тег и удалить ваш вопрос могут. Имейте это ввиду на будущее.